# How to get data from an Object containing an Array in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I have created a collection on Firebase and the data returned from the API is such:

```
documents: Array[2]{
    0: name: "randomString",
        {fields: 
            {name: aName, id: 1}
            },
    1: name: "randomString",
        {fields: 
            {name: aName2, id: 2}
           }
    }
```

On my front end I have an array of objects and I simple want to map each of those array members too it. When I try to assign the response from the API to my local array I obviously get an error because its trying to send an object into an array that doesn't correspond to my local data model:

```
getData() {
    this.dataService.getData()
      .subscribe( res => this.localArray = res; )
  }
```

data-service.ts

```
getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res.documents));
  }
```

How can I map this affectively using Angular. Note that "Response" has been deprecated. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you also show the implementation of `getData()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `res.documents`. the array is on the property documents in your response

Answer (score 0):

In your service you should write

```
return this.http.get(YOUR_API_URL).pipe(map(response => response.documents));
```

And then in your component you just do the following:

```
getData() {
  this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => {
    this.localArray = res;
  });
}
```

Comment: That almost works for me! but the issue is that that maps the random "name" assigned by Firebase to my data models name. What I want to do is extract the properties out of the "fields" section and map it to my local object. I have updated my post to make it clearer. Thanks